# Extracting WMS metadata within polygon using ModelBuilder in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, wms, metadata

Is it possible to extract metadata from different WMS services within a specific polygon using ModelBuilder in ArcMap from, for example, "https://wms.geonorge.no/skwms1/wms.banenettverk?request=GetCapabilities&service=WMS"?

Comment: Do you mean metadata, or do you mean attribute data from the underlying data source?

Comment: Attribute information at a point location in the `kilometerpunkt` layer would be  obtained through a GetFeatureInfo request like: `https://wms.geonorge.no/skwms1/wms.banenettverk?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&BBOX=61.39788570744679674,10.65016029326923075,66.40196929255317571,13.99638691826923065&CRS=EPSG:4326&WIDTH=329&HEIGHT=492&LAYERS=kilometerpunkt&STYLES=&FORMAT=image/png&QUERY_LAYERS=kilometerpunkt&INFO_FORMAT=text/html&I=84&J=290&FEATURE_COUNT=10`

Comment: Metadata for layer `kilometerpunkt` would be `https://wms.geonorge.no:80/cgi-bin/banenettverk?request=GetMetadata&layer=kilometerpunkt` obtained from parsing the GetCapabilities response

Comment: Thats just getting the information manually and not automating it using ModelBuilder based on a polygon is it not? Lets say I draw a polygon over a large part of the WMS layer, how to I get to extract data from the WMS layer such as "kilometerpunkt"?

Comment: Just asking for clarification as to what you wanted with examples, metadata, or attributes.  It appears from your comment that you want attributes, not metadata.

Comment: There is no mechanism in the WMS specification to get attributes for a request based on a polygon.  The way of getting attribute data is GetFeatureInfo and that acts on a point location.

Comment: If what @nmtoken is showing could be written in python then that python code could be put inside a Calculate Value tool to allow it to be run from within modelbuilder. Can it be done from a polygon, I don't know as web-stuff is not my skillset?

Comment: One possible way would be to do a GetFeatureInfo request for every pixel in the GetMap image, but even with `FEATURE_COUNT=1` there would be a  chance of data duplication that you need to handle somehow